# Dynamic INSERT with full variables in PHP

Tags: php, insert

I would appreciate it if someone can guide me with the following problem, I need to do a INSERT into a MySQL database with variables, here is my code example:

```
    $valor = "$valor.", ".$total;
    $table = $dta.$year;
    $insert = "ano, id, idas".$valor2.", total";
    $value = $year.", ".$id.", ".$idas.$tit2.", ".$monto3;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`$insert`) VALUES (`$value`)";
```

The general idea is that the amount of columns are not known until the program is run as it is all dynamic.

The following code is used to build the table as needed, which works fine:

```
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== FALSE)
        {

        $columna=$row['pn'];

        $valor= $valor." pt".$columna." VARCHAR(50),";
        $valor2= $valor2.", pt".$columna;
        $gestion = '3';

        $table = "sumag".$gestion.$year;

        }

        $valor= "ano VARCHAR(4), id VARCHAR(4), idas VARCHAR(13), ".$valor." "."total VARCHAR(10)";
```

For this reason the first code also has to be dynamic..
I really need help on this, I am not a programmer and I have built this from what I have learnt, so most probally my tecnique is pretty bad, if anyone can help it would be great..

Thank You

Comment: syntax highlighting shows you that you've a syntax error; check for them. You have many.

Comment: you're **not** checking for errors. Do that then come back and tell us what those are; again, you have many. If you're just going to reply to answers, then stay with them. I'm out.

Comment: [stop using the **deprecated** mysql_* extension](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vWijtCThtw8/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: yes exactly now i shown it i am totally agree with @Fred-ii-

Comment: You are try to print your query and execute in manually in your database may be you should try it you will get your answers

Comment: You are relying on `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: also consider using an IDE. IT would help in identifying syntax errors as these.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the column name as `idas VARCHAR(13),` in table but the insert element declared with some additional values `idas".$valor2."`. Check this one instance right now..

Comment: Ok $valor is a sting of values with the coma inserted, you can revise this at the top of the code. The idea is to do the following, instead of havunf fixed values in the insert like so: INSTERT TableX (value1, value2, value3) ('$value1', '$value2','$value3');

Comment: to INSERT $table ($value1)($value2);

Comment: I was wondering if it is posible to echo the code to execute it.. something like :  echo '$sql = "INSERT INTO'.$table.'('.$insert.') VALUES ('.$value.')";';

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```
       <?php
       $gestion = 3;
       $data = "SELECT * FROM progdesc where gestion = '$gestion'" or die("¡Error No existe ese departamento!"); 
       $result = mysql_query($data) or die("¡Error No existe ese dep!");
       while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== FALSE)
        {

        $columna=$row['pn'];

        $valor= $valor." pt".$columna." VARCHAR(50),";
        $valor2= $valor2.", pt".$columna;
        $gestion = '3';

        $table = "sumag".$gestion.$year;

    }

    $valor= "ano VARCHAR(4), id VARCHAR(4), idas VARCHAR(13), ".$valor." "."total VARCHAR(10)";

    #echo $table." - ".$valor;      
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$table."`(".$valor.")") or die(mysql_error());

//------------------------------------Insert data -----------------------------------------//


     //-1--------Get Asig N°--------//

$data1 = "SELECT * FROM asigna" or die("¡Error No existe ese departamento!"); 
    $result1 = mysql_query($data1) or die("¡Error1!");
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $idas=$row['idas'];
            $sid=$row['sid'];
            $tit2 = NULL;
            $monto3 = 0;

       //-2-------Get Gestion and DEPFINAL---------------------//


            $data2 = "SELECT * FROM progdesc WHERE gestion = '$gestion' and ano = '$year' " or die("¡Error No existe ese departamento!"); 
        $result2 = mysql_query($data2) or die("¡Error2!");

        while(($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) !== FALSE)
                    {
                        $dep=$row2['departamento'];
                        $titulo=$row2['titulo'];
                        $depf = $dep."final";
                        $pn = $row2['pn'];
                        $sidb = $row2['sid'];
                        #$monto3 = 0;
                        #echo $pn;

     //-3-------Get Program N° and create chain------------//

                $data3 = "SELECT * FROM $depf WHERE ano = '$year' and idas = '$idas' and gestion = '$gestion'and programa = '$pn'  " or die("¡Error No existe ese departamento!"); 
                            $result3 = mysql_query($data3) or die("¡Error3!");

    while(($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $monto=$row3['monto'];
            if (!($idas2 == $idas and $monto == 0)){

            $tit2 =  $tit2.", ".$monto;
            }elseif ($monto == 0){
            $tit2 =  $tit2.", 0";
                } else {
            $cero = 0;
            $pn2 = 0;
            If (!($monto == 0)){
                for ($i = 0; $i < $pn2; $i++) {
                $cero = $cero.", 0";
                }
                $tit2 =  $tit2.", ".$cero.", ".$monto;
                }
        }
    $idas2 = $idas;
    $ln = $ln + 1;
    $monto2 = $monto;
    $monto3 = $monto3 + $monto;
        }
        }
    $insert = "ano, id, idas".$valor2.", total";
        $value = $year.", ".$id.", ".$idas.$tit2.", ".$monto3;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`$insert`) VALUES (`$value`)";
            myquery($sql);    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you've edited in the code? What did OP wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make clear that I am not a programmer and I know my code is not up to standard in any way, I was forced to complete this task just because I kinda know programming, this is why I am asking for help, if there is anther way to complete the task, great and thanks fr all have responded so far, I apreciate your patience.